# 2 versions of amazon-kinesis-client library in one project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I have a project that use the "software.amazon.kinesis:amazon-kinesis-client:2.5.0" library for quite some time for consuming events from kinesis stream.
Recently we started using "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis:3.0.0" library that turns out to have a transitive dependency of this kinesis client but in the older version, in particular "com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.14.9".

As a result, whenever we run an app, it stops consuming events from stream that use version 2.5.0 - there is no error nor exception, it's like it skips its completely.

I'm wondering if the above issue can be caused by a library clash? which in my opinion would be strange as they come from different groups: "software.amazon.kinesis" vs "com.amazonaws" and have different API.

I'm a bit stuck with this situation as there is a lot of old code that uses kinesis client in version 2.5.0, and we made some effort already to develop new code that uses "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis:3.0.0", and doesn't really have time to refactor it.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this situation, without removing any of these libraries?

Thanks

We were checking the possibility of upgrading "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis" to version 4.0.0 ( that internally uses "software.amazon.kinesis:amazon-kinesis-client:2.5.0" ), but unfortunately, it requires at least Spring Boot in version 3.0, and we use version 2.7.
We were also trying to enforce "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis" library to use version 2.5.0 but as I mentioned API is different ant it fails to compile.